# Get image path from file reference in Extbase PHP based view (TYPO3)

Tags: xml, path, typo3, extbase, filereference

I use a PHP based view to return XML in an Extbase extension (TYPO3 6.2). All works great except for the path of images that needs to be included in the XML.

I use the following to get the file reference:

```
$user->addChild('event_image', $event->getPerformance()->getEventImage());
```

The output in XML is:

```
<event_image>TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference:124</event_image>
```

When I try to get the URL path to the image with this code

```
$user->addChild('event_image', $event->getPerformance()->getEventImage()->getImage()->getOriginalResource()->getPublicUrl());
```

I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference::getImage()

My question: How can I get the URL path from the file reference?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a fluid template, take a closer look at `typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Uri/ImageViewHelper.php` within your TYPO3 installation.

That's basically the function call as if you would use the [f:uri.image](http://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ImageViewHelper.html) fluid Viewhelper within your XML template:

```
<event_image><f:uri.image src="{event_image}" treatIdAsReference="1" /></event_image>
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in your code. The method is called getOriginalResource(), not getOriginalRecource().